# How to make everything inside a div margin-right

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` called `wrapper`. I have created this div just recently after changing the layout of my web page and therefore, I have a lot of elements within the `div` which need new CSS styling due to this. All the content within the div is now "stuck" to the right side of the `wrapper` div.

Is there a way to, let's say, apply `margin-right: 10px` to everything within the `wrapper` div, rather than applying the styling individually to each element?

Comment: give some code to us..

Comment: and create a snippet, to demonstrate your issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1

`.wrapper > *` would select every element that is a direct child of the wrapper, so not the elements in the elements in the `wrapper`

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div> <!-- <- this one -->
    <!-- but not elements inside the direct children -->
  </div>
  <!-- all elements here -->
</div>
```

Like this:

```
.wrapper > * {
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

### 2

You could also just put a `padding-right:10px;` on the `.wrapper` like this:

```
.wrapper {
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am Not sure what exactly you are trying to say. However following is a possible scenarios that i can think of

You are trying to say that you have lots of div's and other elements (a, table, etc) inside **wrapper div** and you just want to add spacing (margin) to all those elements all at once. Am I Right? if yes then just create another **div** within wrapper div and apply inline styles to that particular div as follows

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="margin-right: 20px;"> <!--this div will contain all elements--> 

 <!--PLACE ALL OF YOUR ELEMENTS HERE --> 

</div> <!--ending container div--> 
</div> <!--ending wrapper div-->
```

Now Based on your needs you can change the margin value.

Hope my Answer will Help You